# Ruby, how to create a hash from two arrays?

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array, hash

I'm fairly a beginner in Ruby and I'm trying to do the following:
Let's say I have two arrays:

```
array_1 = ["NY", "SF", "NL", "SY"]
array_2 = ["apple", "banana"]
```

I want to merge the arrays to a hash so each object in `array_1` will be assigned with the objects in `array_2`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want as a result?

Comment: The arrays are different lengths so it isn't clear what the resultant `Hash` should look like.

Comment: example of your expected result?

Comment: Best not to post a question and walk away, as it my not be as clear as you think it is, especially considering that you are new to Ruby. Please edit to add the desired result (as opposed to doing that in a comment).

Answer (score 6):

```
x = [:foo, :bar, :baz]
y = [1, 2, 3]
x.zip(y).to_h # => {:foo=>1, :bar=>2, :baz=>3}
```

Comment: This implies that `{ "NY"=>"apple", "SF"=>" banana", "NL"=nil, "SY"= nil }` is the desired result. I may be wrong, but I think you have answered a different question.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, who knows :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `zip` method, like so:

`Hash[array_2.zip(array_1)]`

Comment: This returns `{ 'apple'=>'NY', 'banana'=>'SF' }`. How does that satisfy the requirement that "each object in `array_1` will be assigned with the objects in `array_2`"?

Answer (score 2):

```
h = array_1.product([array_2]).to_h
  #=> {"NY"=>["apple", "banana"], "SF"=>["apple", "banana"],
  #    "NL"=>["apple", "banana"], "SY"=>["apple", "banana"]}
```

We were given [Array#to_h](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h) in MRI v2.0. For earlier versions, use [Kernel#Hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Hash):

```
h = Hash[array_1.product([array_2])]
```

but beware:

```
array_2[0] = "cat"
array_2
  #=> ["cat", "banana"] 
h #=> {"NY"=>["cat", "banana"], "SF"=>["cat", "banana"],
  #    "NL"=>["cat", "banana"], "SY"=>["cat", "banana"]}
```

You may instead want:

```
h = array_1.each_with_object({}) { |str,h| h[str] = array_2.dup }
  #=> {"NY"=>["apple", "banana"], "SF"=>["apple", "banana"],
  #    "NL"=>["apple", "banana"], "SY"=>["apple", "banana"]}

array_2[0] = "cat"
h #=> {"NY"=>["apple", "banana"], "SF"=>["apple", "banana"],
  #    "NL"=>["apple", "banana"], "SY"=>["apple", "banana"]}
```